# Why did answers from June not appear in the Late Answers review queue until October?

Tags: discussion

This morning I was surprised to find answers from June in the Late Answers review queue.  It seems to me that if an answer is late, it should appear in the review queue right away.  This one appeared in the queue four months later.  Is that really how we want the review queue to behave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [scaled to prevent an overly large queue right off the bat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150080/why-does-the-late-answer-review-queue-sometimes-spike-in-size-by-over-5000), so "new" old items are being pushed to it periodically.

This should eventually even out - either once we change the setting (not sure what the plans for that are) or when the queue processes all of the questions/answers on the site.